# System.NullReferenceException Error while parsing Stripe webhook event

Tags: .net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a webhook that handles the following event event:checkout.session.completed
I am getting a null exception while trying to parse the event and I have no idea why.

Here's my webhook:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RecordPayment()
   {
       //  var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

       var json = "{  \"object\": {    \"id\": \"cs_test_a16fFdsLapbbSMWXpjDr2d92tKiAvhz2UdszY6j2EvrCPhxjCmAf0b8SC4\",    \"object\": \"checkout.session\",    \"after_expiration\": null,    \"allow_promotion_codes\": null,    \"amount_subtotal\": 3000,    \"amount_total\": 3000,    \"automatic_tax\": {      \"enabled\": false,      \"status\": null    },    \"billing_address_collection\": null,    \"cancel_url\": \"https://httpbin.org/post\",    \"client_reference_id\": null,    \"consent\": null,    \"consent_collection\": null,    \"created\": 1677855662,    \"currency\": \"usd\",    \"custom_fields\": [    ],    \"custom_text\": {      \"shipping_address\": null,      \"submit\": null    },    \"customer\": null,    \"customer_creation\": \"if_required\",    \"customer_details\": {      \"address\": {        \"city\": null,        \"country\": null,        \"line1\": null,        \"line2\": null,        \"postal_code\": null,        \"state\": null      },      \"email\": \"stripe@example.com\",      \"name\": null,      \"phone\": null,      \"tax_exempt\": \"none\",      \"tax_ids\": [      ]    },    \"customer_email\": null,    \"expires_at\": 1677942062,    \"invoice\": null,    \"invoice_creation\": {      \"enabled\": false,      \"invoice_data\": {        \"account_tax_ids\": null,        \"custom_fields\": null,        \"description\": null,        \"footer\": null,        \"metadata\": {        },        \"rendering_options\": null      }    },    \"livemode\": false,    \"locale\": null,    \"metadata\": {    },    \"mode\": \"payment\",    \"payment_intent\": \"pi_3Mha6XFIOAM5cHmE1dVNi3Ie\",    \"payment_link\": null,    \"payment_method_collection\": \"always\",    \"payment_method_options\": {    },    \"payment_method_types\": [      \"card\"    ],    \"payment_status\": \"paid\",    \"phone_number_collection\": {      \"enabled\": false    },    \"recovered_from\": null,    \"setup_intent\": null,    \"shipping_address_collection\": null,    \"shipping_cost\": null,    \"shipping_details\": null,    \"shipping_options\": [    ],    \"status\": \"complete\",    \"submit_type\": null,    \"subscription\": null,    \"success_url\": \"https://httpbin.org/post\",    \"total_details\": {      \"amount_discount\": 0,      \"amount_shipping\": 0,      \"amount_tax\": 0    },    \"url\": null  }}";

       try
       {
           var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);

           if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted)
           {
               var stripeSession = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Session;
               var model = stripeSession!.Metadata[PaymentConstants.PAYMENT_MODEL];
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) return Ok();

               var paymentModel =
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentModel>(
                       stripeSession!.Metadata[PaymentConstants.PAYMENT_MODEL]);
               Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stripeSession));
               Task.Run(async () => await this._facade.ProcessPaymentAsync(paymentModel));
           }

           return Ok();
       }
       catch (StripeException e)
       {
           return BadRequest();
       }
   }
```

The exception is happening on the following line:

```
 var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);
```

Here's the original event before any change on my part ( this is coming from Stripe Dashbord)

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "xxxxxxx",
    "object": "checkout.session",
    "after_expiration": null,
    "allow_promotion_codes": null,
    "amount_subtotal": 3000,
    "amount_total": 3000,
    "automatic_tax": {
      "enabled": false,
      "status": null
    },
    "billing_address_collection": null,
    "cancel_url": "https://httpbin.org/post",
    "client_reference_id": null,
    "consent": null,
    "consent_collection": null,
    "created": 1677855662,
    "currency": "usd",
    "custom_fields": [
    ],
    "custom_text": {
      "shipping_address": null,
      "submit": null
    },
    "customer": null,
    "customer_creation": "if_required",
    "customer_details": {
      "address": {
        "city": null,
        "country": null,
        "line1": null,
        "line2": null,
        "postal_code": null,
        "state": null
      },
      "email": "stripe@example.com",
      "name": null,
      "phone": null,
      "tax_exempt": "none",
      "tax_ids": [
      ]
    },
    "customer_email": null,
    "expires_at": 1677942062,
    "invoice": null,
    "invoice_creation": {
      "enabled": false,
      "invoice_data": {
        "account_tax_ids": null,
        "custom_fields": null,
        "description": null,
        "footer": null,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "rendering_options": null
      }
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "locale": null,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "mode": "payment",
    "payment_intent": "pi_3Mha6XFIOAM5cHmE1dVNi3Ie",
    "payment_link": null,
    "payment_method_collection": "always",
    "payment_method_options": {
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
      "card"
    ],
    "payment_status": "paid",
    "phone_number_collection": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "recovered_from": null,
    "setup_intent": null,
    "shipping_address_collection": null,
    "shipping_cost": null,
    "shipping_details": null,
    "shipping_options": [
    ],
    "status": "complete",
    "submit_type": null,
    "subscription": null,
    "success_url": "https://httpbin.org/post",
    "total_details": {
      "amount_discount": 0,
      "amount_shipping": 0,
      "amount_tax": 0
    },
    "url": null
  }
}
```

Thanks for any insight

Edit

This is turned out to be my own mistake. I was using the wrong Json payload.

this is how the correct one looks like.

```
{
  "id": "evt_1Mhvn6FIOAM5cHmEC2RxD2PT",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1677939028,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "prod_NSrW1kodrWTwQJ",
      "object": "product",
      "active": true,
      "attributes": [

      ],
      "created": 1677939028,
      "default_price": null,
      "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)",
      "images": [

      ],
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "name": "myproduct",
      "package_dimensions": null,
      "shippable": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "tax_code": null,
      "type": "service",
      "unit_label": null,
      "updated": 1677939028,
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 2,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_FlaNnw2HYsnr32",
    "idempotency_key": "7658e9b3-57e3-4521-a0e0-e4aa9cc10274"
  },
  "type": "product.created"
}
```

Apologies to everyone who was trying to help.

Comment: Does your handler code work if you use the line that's currently commented out?
`var json = await new StreamReader...`

The event you're hardcoding is not a complete Event object from Stripe. You're currently only passing the `data` object that is nested within the Event object. The Event object should also include the Event ID (`evt_...`), type (`event`), and API version: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object

Comment: Hi @LauraT, it does not work either.   I hard-coded it to make the value that is received obvious.